# Are the drivers installed on my machine open source?

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I am using an Asus X501A1 notebook. When I install Ubuntu on it it does not require any extra driver installation to function properly.

I am curious about this - are the drivers installed on my computer open source?

Comment: Close-voters: How is/was it unclear what this question is asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly yes, everything that works out of the box is using open source drivers, included in the kernel (or for graphics some user space part in Xorg libraries).

One exception is the [firmware](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware) that is needed for some devices. It is loaded at hardware initialization for some wireless/wired network adapters, sound cards etc. to function properly. These firmwares are generally closed source, but are redistributable.

The kernel takes care of all drivers - that's why the Linux project is huge; it needs to support all the hardware!